# Почему HttpPostedFileBase file и Request.File не существуют? Как загрузить файл на C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fileupload, upload

Как загрузить файл на сервер Aps Net Core?
Пытаюсь, как пишут, но HttpPostedFileBase file и Request.File не существуют?
Что нужно подключать, что б работал приём файлов?

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" v-on:submit.prevent="GM().send_new_pay()" id="newPay_form">
  <table class="table"> 
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Сделайте скриншот оплаты и прикрепите его здесь</th>
      <td><input id="newPay_file" name="newPay_file" type="file" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">После оплаты нажмите</th>
      <td><button class="btn btn-outline-info">Отправить</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: покажите html *()*

Comment: @Igor   там в контроллере ругается, что не может скомпилировать мой код для сохранения